# Recommend me a good JNI book

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm creating a software project in Java, is a remote administration tool. The thing is that I need to add some features with C++ and I read some about this process and I realized I need JNI, could you recommend me a good JNI Book or something related with ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this?

[Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/)

This book is quite good I think.